# Выделение всего рисунка в Photoshop

Tags: веб-дизайн, дизайн, photoshop

Каким образом (с помощью каких клавиш или пунктов меню) можно выделить **весь** рисунок  в Photoshop?

Comment: Ctrl+A обычно ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых нужно выделить все слои

> Выделить все слои в панели слоёв разом одним кликом можно, нажав
> комбинацию клавиш **Ctrl+Alt+A**. Выделяются все слои, кроме фонового, но
> на него можно кликнуть позже, зажав Ctrl.

Если нужно объединить все слои, то **Shift+Ctrl+E** или же **Shift+Ctrl+Alt+E** что бы объединить в новом слое

После выделяются все пиксели **Ctrl+A**